# Drawing in JS not working

Tags: javascript, html, 3d

I'm making a 3d game in java script and this image is not drawing.
No errors come up in the console ether. It tells me it drew but I dont see anything. Its not a problem with the source. It tells me theres a wall there yet it does not draw. I know its not a problem with the canvas.

full code:http://jsfiddle.net/andmoreguy/wja8atd0/

Declaring Image:

```
var wall1 = new Image();
```

Declaring Map:

```
var map = [];
map = [
[1,1,1,1,1,1],
[1,0,0,0,1,1],
[1,0,0,0,0,1],
[1,0,0,0,0,1],
[1,0,0,0,0,1],
[1,1,1,1,1,1]
];
```

Declaring height Map:

```
var height = [];
height = [
[9,9,4,1,3,1],
[1,0,0,0,3,4],
[2,0,0,0,0,5],
[3,0,0,0,0,6],
[4,0,0,0,0,7],
[5,6,7,8,9,8]
];
```

Render function a = 45:

```
function renderblocks(a){
var j = 0;
for(var i = 0;i < 7;i++){
    var check = checkblocks(a + j, i)
    if(check == true){wall.onload = wall(i, dist);
    console.log(true);
    }
    wall1.src = "assets/slide.png";
    j++;
}
}
```

The checkblocks function:

```
function checkblocks(a, numb){
var stepy = 64;
var stepx = 64/Math.tan(a);
for(i=0;i<3;i++){
    var x = stepx*i;
    var y = stepy*i;
    x = x/64;
    y = y/64;
    console.log(map[x][y])
    dist = stepy * i / a;
    if (map[x][y] == 1){ return true;}
}
}
```

and the Wall function:

```
function wall(numb, dist){
ctx.drawImage(wall1,numb*91,4,91,height[x][y]*64);
console.log("it drew")
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay.  From your code, I'm not too sure what you want the final product to look like, or what you want to do with the heights.  But I made an example that uses the 1s and 0s of the map to draw or not draw wall sections on the canvas.  Play around with this and I think you'll get it.

```
for (var m = 0;m<6;m++){
    for (var n=0;n<6;n++){
        if(map[m][n]){
            ctx.drawImage(wall1,m*50,n*50,50,50); 
        }
    }
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/askkaz/e30fcte5/)

Comment: sorry I forgot to add that in my code check the edit

Comment: do you also declare wall1 as a global somewhere?

Comment: its not inside a function, if that's what you mean.

Comment: what is your canvas size?

Comment: and when you call wall, what are x and y defined as?  (the ones that you have in your question are limited to the scope of checkblocks)

Comment: try changing your code to this and tell me what it prints:
function wall(numb, dist){
ctx.drawImage(wall1,numb*91,4,91,height[x][y]*64);
console.log("it drew")
console.log("x" + x);
console.log("y" + y);
}

Comment: well I just made them global but that did't fix anything

Comment: can you post the full version of your code or a jsfiddle?